# How to connect a SilentStepStick TMC2130 stepper driver?

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper

please excuse the noob question

Am connecting a [SilentStepStick](https://github.com/watterott/SilentStepStick/blob/master/hardware/SilentStepStick-TMC2130_v11.pdf) to arduino with a stepper, for bench testing.

It requires 5V power, plus I have a 24V power supply for the steppers.
+5V connected to Vio, and +24V connection to VM.

Question: how to connect the grounds?  The device has two GND pins.  Should I just connect one ground, from the 5V power supply, to avoid ground loops?

Or should grounds from both power supplies be connected?

Thankyou for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: (from Electrical Engineering), yes both grounds must be connected.

In this example, +5V and GND from the arduino would connect to the two top left pins in the diagram (Vio & GND).

The two 24v power lines would connect to the bottom left two pins, Vm & GND

Comment: Aren't the grounds connected to each other on the board, and so couldn't you connect either ground to either pin?

Comment: According to the .brd file found at Watterotts github, yes, both grounds are connected to the same ground plane on the PCB.